# Xamarin Android Player hangs during startup

Tags: android, xamarin, virtualbox

My Android Player has stopped working. When I start one of my installed devices,  the emulator window does not open. I can see it in the process bar, and there is a VBoxHeadless process running.

I looked at the VirtualBox log for the device. The last line says "00:02:58.209802 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.3.15".
There are two host-only Networks in VirtualBox (these were installed by Android Player):

- VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 
  Adapter:
  IPv4 Address: 10.71.34.1
  IPv4 Network Mask: 255.0.0.0
  DHCP Server:
  Enabled Server (checked)
  Server Address: 10.71.34.2
  Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
  Lower Address Bound: 10.71.34.101
  Upper Address Bound: 10.71.34.199
- VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  Adapter:
  IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
  IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
  DHCP Server:
  Enabled Server (checked)
  Server Address: 192.168.56.100
  Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
  Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.101
  Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254

The Device is configured by Android Player to use the first one of these (VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2).

This worked for me until yesterday. I have attempted the following to resolve the issue:

- Reinstalled Android Player and VirtualBox
- Installed the latest version of VirtualBox (4.3.22)
- Deleted and re-Installed the Device (and several different devices)
- Manually changed the Network Adapter for the device to point to the second configured adapter - but this is changed back to the "#2"-device by Android Player when it starts the Device.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Also, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Which windows version you have?you say this worked until yesterday, what was changed since then?
Consider using genymotion for now, Xamarin Android Player is in beta state and it is buggy and slow for now.